# Java library to set precision and scale for double/float

Tags: java, precision, number-formatting

Is there any Java library that can help me implement this scenario.

Max number of precision: 3
Max number of decimal scale: 1

e.g. the output should be 33.0, 21.9, 3.4, 100, etc.

The 100 here doesn't have a decimal scale with trailing zero cause it has already exceeded the precision(3).

Comment: Not for `double` and `float`, but `BigDecimal` is certainly a library that would do this for you.  (Arguably, it's outright impossible for `double` and `float`.)

Comment: I'd just use an integer for internal representation.

Comment: [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)